# Docker-compose does not install or run properly on boot2docker

Tags: docker, boot2docker, docker-compose

I have successfully installed docker-machine on my Windows computer, and I'm able to use the Docker CLI on my windows box to run docker commands on a boot2docker VM.

I have docker-machine version 0.2.0, and docker 1.6.2, and the VM yields "4.0.3-boot2docker" when I run "uname -r" on it.

Now I want to install docker-compose to manage that boot2docker VM. **Does docker-compose run on my Windows machine and manage the VM "remotely", as docker does, or do I have to install it on the VM itself?**

On a related note, I tried installing docker-compose on my VM by doing the following:

```
C:\ docker-machine ssh dev
$ whoami
docker
$ sudo -i
# curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.2.0/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` > /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
# chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
# exit
$ which docker
/usr/local/bin/docker
$ which docker-compose
/usr/local/bin/docker-compose
```

This is fine, but when I try to run docker-compose it doesn't work.

```
$ docker-compose up
-sh: docker-compose: not found
```

The file is in /usr/local/bin, and it has exactly the same privileges as docker.

```
docker@dev:/usr/local/bin$ ls -al do*
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root      15443675 May 13 21:24 docker
-rwxr-xr-x    1 root     root       5263681 May 19 00:09 docker-compose
docker@dev:/usr/local/bin$
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: what happens when you run `/usr/local/bin/docker-compose` ?

Comment: Same thing.... -sh: docker-compose: not found

Comment: Docker Compose runs "remotely" (as you say) by looking at the `$DOCKER_HOST` URL defined on your local machine. By changing this variable, you will run your `docker-compose` commands against the Docker daemon running at that URL. Hence, you don't have to install Docker Compose on your VM; it is a dev tool and should reside on your local dev machine.

Answer (score 2):

Have a good look at the `curl` output. It seems that the download url is not valid anymore. I found that

```
curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.2.0/docker-compose-Linux-x86_x64
```

gave

```
{"error":"Not Found"}
```

For me, the current [release 1.3.2](https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/tag/1.3.2) worked well, i.e.:

```
curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.3.2/docker-compose-Linux-x86_x64
```

**NOTE:** When using on current CoreOS don't try to output in `/usr/local/bin/docker-compose` as noted [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-docker-extension/issues/9). Instead use `/opt/bin/docker-compose` (dir may need to be created first), i.e.

```
mkdir -p /opt/bin
curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.3.2/docker-compose-Linux-x86_x64 > /opt/bin/docker-compose
```

Answer (score 1):

I found that the download links don't work for older versions and the "install" fails silently resulting in the problem you describe. Have a look to find a download link to a current version here:

https://github.com/docker/compose/releases

Like mkoertgen said, you can always view the output from the curl command in the terminal to see that you don't get "not found" or something similar or run cat /usr/local/bin/docker-compose to verify that it's not a textfile containing "not found".

Answer (score 0):

You can install docker-compose on your Windows host too.
It will manage your docker remotely. You can think of docker-compose as a more abstract interface to docker.

After running `boot2docker init`, run `boot2docker shellinit | Invoke-Expression`. This will tell docker and docker-compose where the docker server is running.

More info on installing it on Windows can be found here: http://docs.docker.com/installation/windows/

Comment: AFAIK there is no docker-compose binary for Windows. I know of options: 1) run docker-compose as a container, 2) python build via pip (which doesn't work on windows because of missing dependencies). Do you you mean 1) was integrated in boot2docker somehow?

Comment: I never ran docker or docker-compose on Windows. But docker-compose is released as a python package installable via pip. So I think is just run "pip install docker-compose" as I do on other SOs.

Comment: Nope, python binary cannot be installed due to missing dependencies